# OLS Estimators: substitute $\beta$ with $\hat{\beta}$

Tags: least-squares

I was reading [this note](https://web.stanford.edu/~mrosenfe/soc_meth_proj3/matrix_OLS_NYU_notes.pdf) on OLS and I saw they substitute $\beta$ with $\hat{\beta}$ like this:

Recall 
$$ X^TX \hat{\beta} = X^Ty$$

Now substitute in $y = X\hat{\beta} + \epsilon$ to get

$$ X^TX \hat{\beta} = X^T(X\hat{\beta} + \epsilon)$$
$$ = X^TX\hat{\beta} + X^T \epsilon $$

meaning that
$$ X^T \epsilon = 0$$

My question is how can we have $y = X\hat{\beta} + \epsilon$? if so, doesn't that mean $\hat{\beta} = \beta$ ? but this is impossible.

Comment: The substitution they make is actually $y = X\hat{\beta} + e$, where $e$ is the vector of residuals. In their notation, $\epsilon$ is the vector of stochastic disturbance terms. See the footnote on the first page.

Comment: You are right. Thank you @rzch . Am I stupid or something ...

Comment: It's a perfectly fine mistake to make, we all do it